# AndroidStudio 0.8.2 Run App or Debug App fails

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, apk

I have generated an app with navigation drawer using the wizard.

When I choose Run 'App' or Debug 'App' I get this error:

[image: app-release-unsigned.apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected flavor using the Project Structure dialog]

The Generate Signed APK... option works and it creates the signed app which can be installed on the phone and works.
Also make or rebuild project works in debug or release without errors.

I have configured the signing information in project structure, but I get the same error. Also I have another older app which runs or debugs without this error and have the same gradle.build, except that the last one is targeted to sdk 20

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.06"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/AppRate_1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/gallery-lib.jar')
    compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader.jar')
}
```

- Make project works.
- Rebuild project works.
- Generate Signed APK works.
- Run 'App' fails
- Debug 'App' fails

Comment: More info needed, can't help you ...

Comment: I have added more info

Comment: This build.gradle file is ok. What's your Run/Debug Configurations ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered the same problem today

-Close the project and import again.